# Led Strip via USB?

Tags: usb, rgb, led

Is there a way to attach a LED strip to a usb cable, so i can power it with my pc?
The LED strip got the following connections:

- red
- blue
- green
- power(about 5V)

Comment: we need more information on the LED.  What are its connection options?

Comment: oh i found the manual: supply voltage DC 5V 12V 24V
output current 2A per color i hope that helps, but i think 24 V is too much for usb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

critical is the wattage which is *voltage x current*. an USB port has voltage 5V (+- 0.25 V) and a maximal output current of 1A so the maximal wattage it can transfer is ~ 5W. your LED strip very likely has a wattage of around 10W (5V x 2A = 10W) so you should not use it on an USB port. critical is not the voltage but the current it will draw (overcurrent). normally USB ports have an overcurrent protection but i would not test this. there are USB led strips for this see search ...

Comment: ty, didnt want to throw it away xD